# ExtJS changing form component POST data format

Tags: javascript, post, extjs

I want to be able to change how an ExtJS Component formats the POST data.

To be more specific I am using the MultiSelect user extension. The post data is formatted with a single param with comma separated values.

i.e. multiSelect = 1,2,3

The way in which I need to handle this is to have multiple identical attributes

i.e. multiSelect=1 multiSelect=2 multiSelect=3

The MutliSelect component is the following

```
var multiselect = new Ext.ux.Multiselect({
    name              :  'multiselect',
    fieldLabel        :  'Multiselect',
    dataFields        :  ['code', 'desc'], 
    data              :  [['1', 'One'], ['2', 'Two'], ['3', 'Three'], ['4','Four'], ['5', 'Five']],
    valueField        :  'code',
    displayField      :  'desc',
    width             :  150,
    height            :  150,
    allowBlank        :  true
});
```

Comment: Are you using this multi-select? http://www.figtreesystems.com/ext/ext-ux/1.1/Multiselect/Multiselect.html Does that mean you are using Ext 1.1?

Comment: I am using multiselect, but the newer version. The code above was the example given, but I must have copied from the wrong version...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% that this will work, but I suspect doing something like this should:

```
Ext.override(Ext.ux.Multiselect, {
  getValue: function() {
    var returnArray = [],
      selectionsArray = this.view.getSelectedIndexes(),
      i;
    for (i = 0; i < selectionsArray.length; i++) {
     returnArray.push(this.store.getAt(selectionsArray[i]).get(((valueField != null)? valueField : this.valueField)));
    }
    return returnArray;
  }
});
```

Sending an array should get it to use normal `Ext.urlEncode` behaviour.

Comment: the value of the post data attribute needs to be a single number. I tried changing it to an array but its still not being handled properly. Thanks for the suggestion, it many situations that would work

Comment: If Ext.urlEncode encounters an array for its value it will output `foo=a&foo=b`. What's happening at the moment is that the `getValue` function returns a string.

Comment: My issue is that the getValue() is also being used elsewhere (in a user extension) and changing it to an array breaks that one too

Comment: Do `Ext.ux.MyMultiSelect = Ext.extend(Ext.ux.MultiSelect, { getValue: ... })` and use that instead?

Answer (score 0):

Configure the component to have a null delimiter, i.e. delimiter: null (see api documentation)